# Executing two create functions cloud functions

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions

I'm creating a cloud function for when a user signs up, first to create a score collection from them, but then I also want to add some dummy starter data to their account but the below won't work because the second return statement is never reached.

If there are any suggestions on a better way to do this entirely, then I welcome that feedback.

```js
  // auth trigger (new user signup)
  exports.newUserSignup = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {

      return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('score').add({
          gems: 0,
      })

      //this line isn't reached

      return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('sampleData').add({
          ...
      });

  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to wait until the promises from both operations resolve.  One way to do this is to generate a new promise that resolves only after the other two resolve.

```
exports.newUserSignup = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {

    const p1 = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('score').add({
        gems: 0,
    })
    
    const p2 = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('sampleData').add({
        ...
    });

    return Promise.all([p1, p2]);
})
```

In order to make effective use of JavaScript and Cloud Functions, you will definitely need to understand how asynchronous programming with JavaScript promises work. I suggest taking some time to learn about that.

Comment: Thank you, also I forgot to ask about adding multiple documents at once, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62725967/adding-multiple-documents-in-cloud-functions Thank you