# Adding multiple documents in cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I want to add multiple documents in the sampleData collection?
Also, there is a serverTimeStamp property on the sampleData, how can I add this as well.

sampleData looks like:

name: String

serverTimeStamp: serverTimeStamp

tags: Array []

```
exports.newUserSignup = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {

    const p1 = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('score').add({
        gems: 0,
    })
    
    const p2 = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('sampleData').add({
        ...
    });

    return Promise.all([p1, p2]);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To [add a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) you may use .doc().set(...) or as in your case .add(...), which are completely equivalent.

If you are looking to add multiple documents, you may want to consider batch writes. As you would be able to execute multiple write operations as a single batch that contains any combination of set(), update(), or delete() operations. More information can be found through this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/transactions?hl=no#node.js_2).